# Calculate $\mathbb{E}\tau$

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stopping-times

Let $X = (X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ be a non-negative stochastic process such that
\begin{equation}
dX_t = 7dt + 2\sqrt{X_t}dB_t, \quad X_0 = 0
\end{equation}
with $B= (B_t)_{t\geq 0}$ a standard Brownian motion. Now let $\tau = \inf\{t\geq 0: X_t = |5-4t|\}$. I want to calculate $\mathbb{E}\tau$, but I do not know how to manage the modulus. Any hint, please?

Comment: A picture might convince you that $X_\tau=5-4\tau$. (Because $X_t\ge 0$ for all t.)

Comment: @JohnDawkins: why $X_t \ge 0$ then $X_{\tau} = 5-4\tau$ ? How do you prove that $5-4\tau  \ge 0$ ?

Comment: The graph of $t\mapsto |5-4t|$ starts at $5$ when $t=0$, falls linearly to $0$ at $t=1.25$, then rises linearly thereafter, with slope $4$. The process $X_t$, which starts with $X_0=0$ and satisfies $X_t\ge 0$ for all $t>0$, will hit that graph for the first time at some $\tau\in[0,1.25]$. At that time, $0\le X_\tau = 5-4\tau$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins: Ok I see now. Thanks.